# Async Methods Confusion

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to wrap my head around asynchronous methods and I am wondering what the difference is between the following two methods.

```
public Task Add(Tenant tenant)
{
    DbContext.Tenants.Add(tenant);
    return DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}

public async Task Add(Tenant tenant)
{
    DbContext.Tenants.Add(tenant);
    await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First one is *synchronous* method, which returns `Task`.
Second one is *asynchronous* method, which awaits another asynchronous operation at the end of the method (tail-call).

There is a [proposed optimization](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/1981) for Roslyn, which will convert second one to first one, when possible.

Comment: ah that makes sense thank you for the clear explanation!

Comment: actually both return `Task` and both can be awaited

Comment: @enkryptor: yes, that's true. But first one has no awaits, and compiler doesn't generate any `async` state machine code. This is just synchronous method.

Answer (score 1):

Your second variant introduces a *slight* overhead. The compiler has to emit a lot of boilerplate to effectively allow the current method to be resumed.

In both cases, what your method returns is a `Task` which will be completed once `SaveChangesAsync` has completed all of the requested work asynchronously. But in the first case, what you're returning is the exact `Task` that `SaveChangesAsync` returned itself.

Whereas in the second case, what you're returning is a new `Task` object. And then, as I say, the overhead to allow your method to mark this new `Task` as complete as soon as `SaveChangesAsync` marks *its* `Task` as complete.